# Power Automation embedded image from get attachment

Tags: power-automate

I use Get Attachment anf want to embedded image
`<img src="data&colon;image/png;base64,@{outputs('Get_Attachment_(V2)')?['body/contentBytes']}" >`

The ISSUE is when use Content Bytes image does not show, instead i see it includes some odd special characters such as � I think problem is with incorrect encoding, Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

```
base64( outputs('Get_Attachment_(V2)')?['body/contentBytes'] )
```

Comment: I use this <img src="base64( outputs('Get_Attachment_(V2)')?['body/contentBytes'] )"  width="100%" height="100%" > but image not showing. I also try this <img src="data:image/png;base64( outputs('Get_Attachment_(V2)')?['body/contentBytes'] ) />